# How to hide table rows when the value is null

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I am creating a project in eclipse where I want to display values input into a form in a table. I want the table to only display the rows which have values, but cannot work out how to do this. So far I have just added multiple rows and am using `display:none` in order to not display them, but I do not cannot think of a way to get the `th:text="${name1}"` to display.

Here is an example of the way I am doing it so far:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr id="tableRow">
      <th class="tableHeader">Name</th>
      <th class="tableHeader">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableRow" style="display:none">
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name1}"></td>
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description1}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableRow" style="display:none">
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name2}"></td>
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description2}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableRow" style="display:none">
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name3}"></td>
      <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description3}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am relatively new to coding and so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is: `th:text="${description3}`? I don't know any attribute like that and `$` looks more like PHP than JavaScript.

Comment: @domsson It's thymeleaf, I'm running this on a localhost and pulling what is written in the form from an h2 databse.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the question was re-tagged from Javascript to Java while I was typing my comment. Makes more sense now. I took the liberty to add the thymeleaf tag for you.

Comment: @domsson No worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way to do it using `th:each`:

```
    <table id="table">
        <tr id="tableRow">
            <th class="tableHeader">Name</th>
            <th class="tableHeader">Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tableRow" th:each="inputMap : ${InputMap}">
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${inputMap.value.name}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${inputMap.value.description}"></td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

The `${InputMap}` comes from my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/tablePage")
public void getTableData(Model model) {

    inputRepository.findAll().forEach(inputObject -> {
        inputMap.put(inputObject.id, inputObject);
    });

    if (inputMap != null){
        inputMap.forEach((id, i) -> {
            model.addAttribute(id + "name", id + i.getName());
            model.addAttribute(id + "description", id + i.getDescription());
        });
    }

    model.addAttribute("InputMap", inputMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to test values before consuming it

```html
<table id="table">
        <tr id="tableRow">
            <th class="tableHeader">Name</th>
            <th class="tableHeader">Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tableRow" th:if="${name1 != null or description1 != null}">
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name1}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description1}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tableRow" th:if="${name2 != null or description2 != null}">
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name2}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description2}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tableRow" th:if="${name3 != null or description3 != null}">
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${name3}"></td>
            <td class="tableCell" th:text="${description3}"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```